# How big is the impact of hardware on robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle) rate?

Tags: java, screenshot, hardware

I just figured out a portion of code in my app working well on my laptop (i5 2.9Ghz, 8 GB Ram 1TB Disk, I think my graphic card is a GTX850 but I'm not sure) was based on the following pattern:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300) //300 biggest possible
while(cond){
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
}
```

Might not work so well on another computer?

Because it works only at 60fps otherwise results won't make sense.

If not, which hardware characteristics will influence it (cpu ghz, ram, graphic card...)?

Comment: I could sell you a potato for 900 euros and claim it's a good laptop. Price doesn't say anything about specs

Comment: Guess what I then wouldn't buy that potato :-D I get your point, but I don't have my laptop with me, I'll try to remember and edit.